# html force english lang in input number step

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01"  min="0" name="weight" id="weight" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="weight ( kg )">
```

[show image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TnpQ.jpg)

is there any way to force english in input number?
always showing as arabic format

Answer (score 1):

you can use lang="en" or dir="ltr"

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01"  min="0" name="weight" id="weight" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="weight ( kg )" lang="en">
```

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01"  min="0" name="weight" id="weight" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="weight ( kg )" dir="ltr">
```

Comment: https://snipboard.io/0a7JPY.jpg  not working

Comment: @MoNabil This is most likely your browser issue and its forcing Arabic as the primary language regardless of the HTML Code, open an INCOGNITO tab and check. tomerar solution is correct.